# Swap all key:value pairs for a literal dictionary in PyCharm

Tags: python, regex, pycharm

Now and then I'll write out a literal dictionary and then realize I inadvertently swapped the keys/values:

```
MY_DICT = {"VALUE1":"KEY1", "VALUE2":"KEY2"} # <- WHOOPS!
```

Sometimes such a dictionary can be a bit long, and it is a lot of typing to go back and swap all the keys/values.

One way to fix this is to copy the dict to the interpreter and do a:

```
{v:k for k,v in MY_DICT.values()}
```

...and copy/paste the result. But of course, this is also a lot of typing.

The following regex in the Find field would capture key/value group pairs for a dictionary with 6 entries:

```
\{(.*): (.*), (.*): (.*), (.*): (.*), (.*): (.*), (.*): (.*), (.*): (.*)\}
```

...I can then swap them like this in the Replace field:

```
{$2: $1, $4: $3, $6: $5, $8: $7, $10: $9, $12: $11}
```

Is there a more generic way to execute this find/replace? If I can come up with something, I was thinking of adding a custom `SwapDict` command to my PyCharm IDE.

(Complicating things, of course, is we probably cannot count on having nice single-spaces after every colon and comma. And the keys/values might also contain colons sometimes! This is the real world, after all.)

Maybe another approach would be to abandon the regex entirely and teach PyCharm a new Alt+Enter trick: take the `dict`, swap the keys/values, and replace the literal `dict` with the result. I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Couldn't you do this `re.sub(r'("[^"]+")(:\s*)("[^"]+")', "\\3\\2\\1", str, 0)`?

Comment: can you assume that there are no strings with curly braces?  are all keys and values strings?

Comment: @e.s. No, not all are strings. Some might be object names. I suppose a string could have braces.

Comment: Could be wrong but this might be out of the reach of regex- regex can't parse HTML because of the matching tag pairs, and similarly you can't even write a regex that matches any other regex. This might be a similar kind of problem?

Comment: Regex can't parse HTML because it has a tree-structure. Fallen in a top-down hierarchy which naturally is able to be nested. If you reply on my first comment (about possibilities) I might be able to help.

Comment: If you need to do that in a text editor, I'd recommend Notepad++ where you may use [`(?:\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*|\bMY_DICT\s*=\s*\{)\K("[^"]+")(\s*:\s*)("[^"]+")` to replace with `$3$2$1`](https://regex101.com/r/PqewFk/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Pretty nice (I also am a heavy Npp++ user). However the regex doesn't work for non-string object references, e.g. `{VALUE_OBJ1:"KEY1", VALUE_OBJ2:"KEY2"}`.

Comment: To slightly adapt the above for use with Pycharm: [`(\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*|\bMY_DICT\s*=\s*\{)(\"[^\"]+\")(:\s*)(\"[^\"]+\")`](https://regex101.com/r/aMciMD/2)

Comment: Like https://regex101.com/r/PqewFk/2?